Movie about kid forced to watch mauled pigs
So, this was on TV some time ago (and by some time, I mean a few years) and basically, there was this boy who was sitting in like one of those indoor PE bleachers (stands?) or something like that. 
In the middle.of the room, there are all these pigs and then someone releases dogs from somewhere and all these pigs just get mauled (I'm pretty certain they were pigs...?)
Then it cuts to the kid sitting in the stand trying to look away from the carnage, but some man keeps forcing his face in that direction.

What is "a few years"... for some people that's five, for others, it's 30.

By a few years, I mean around possibly 3 to 5-ish. I'm pretty sure it was ION Television, if that helps at all.

How old is the kid, guess?

This resembles one scene from the movie Snatch, but only if is was the pigs doing the mauling...
Iirc, in Snatch, there is a scene where Tommy (the most boyish among the cast) is being held and forced to watch Brick-Top's pigs going through some corpses, while Brick-Top "negociates" with Turkish, Tommy's partner/mentor.
But it could be completely wrong, as you mention the boy sitting in the room, whereas in Snatch he is standing above the room...

Maybe you're thinking of the movie Soldier . The start of the movie they show how they train children to be soldiers from birth. One of the parts of the training is where they are shown a group of pigs getting killed by dogs, the boy looks away but he is forced to watch by an instructor. I cant find a clip of the scene but it sounds similar to what you are describing.

Hi, could you add some more detail to this answer so that readers can judge without having to look it up whether this film is likely to match the description in the question?
